# What's wrong with my binding?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm working on an application using a TCP protocol.
I want to show the different statuses of the communication in different colors (connect = green, disconnect = red)

I defined an enum:

```
public enum ComunicationStateTypeEnum
    {
        COMUNICATION_CONNECTED,

        COMUNICATION_DISCONNECTED

    };
```

I defined a conversion class:

```
namespace Conversion
{
[ValueConversion(typeof(ComunicationStateTypeEnum), typeof(Brushes))]
public class ComStatusToColor : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ComunicationStateTypeEnum state = (ComunicationStateTypeEnum)value;
        if (state == ComunicationStateTypeEnum.COMUNICATION_CONNECTED)
            return Brushes.Green;
        return Brushes.Red;            
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

}

In Xaml I defined an ellipse:

```
 <Ellipse Name="ComEllipse" Height="25" Width="30" Fill ="{Binding Path=eCommStatus, Converter={StaticResource ComStatusToColor}}" Stroke="Black" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
```

also in Xaml I defined:

```
xmlns:ConversionNamespace="clr-namespace:Conversion"    
<Window.Resources>        
    <ConversionNamespace:ComStatusToColor x:Key="ComStatusToColor"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

I want to bind to an existing object, therefore I initiated:

```
ComEllipse.DataContext = SystemLogic.GetInstance();
```

(SystemLogic is a singleton)

and in SystemLogic I defined:

```
public class SystemLogic
{
public ComunicationStateTypeEnum eCommStatus { get; set; }
...
}
```

eCommStatus is initiated to COMUNICATION_DISCONNECTED in the constructor and the ellipse turns red, and still when eCommStatus member changes to COMUNICATION_CONNECTED , the ellipse doesn't change its color

What's wrong?

Gil

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your `SystemLogic` class to let UI know that a property's value has changed. This way UI can update itself.

### Example

```
public class SystemLogic : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ComunicationStateTypeEnum _eCommStatus;
    public ComunicationStateTypeEnum eCommStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return _eCommStatus;
        }
        set
        {
            _eCommStatus = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("eCommStatus");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler temp = PropertyChanged;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your binding. But SystemLogic must implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) to report back when it is changed.

```
public class SystemLogic
{
    private ComunicationStateTypeEnum _eCommStatus;
    public ComunicationStateTypeEnum eCommStatus 
    { 
        get{return _eCommStatus;} 
        set
        {
            _eCommStatus = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ComunicationStateTypeEnum");
        }
    }
...
}
```